# How to export from SQLExpress, Import to SQL Standard

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to find how I can export certain data from one sql server (remote location, 2008 SQLExpress) and import into our sql server (SQL Standard 2008).

My first thought was to setup the remote server to use BCP queries w/ stored jobs and export data to csv files and then FTP to our location and then import.  However, from what I can see stored job is not an option with SQL Express.
Is that the case?

How else could I create a solution (without buying sql licenses)?

Comment: Right now I am trying sqlcmd, but trying to remove the hyphen row between header/detail.

Comment: Can you show some sample data? And how you want to store it in SQL 2008.